# The difference between libel and slander

Tags: libel, slander

I've heard people use the terms libel and slander interchangeably, but I know that they are different in the eyes of the law. What are the defining characteristics of each?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From http://grammarist.com/usage/libel-slander/:

(emphasis mine)

> **Libel** is the use of false, defamatory claims about someone in **written or printed form**. **Slander** likewise denotes false statements that damage a person’s reputation, but it is committed **orally or in any other transient form**

So a false claim satisfying the definition of defamation would be libel if written (including on the Internet, per [Varian Medical Systems, Inc. v. Delfino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varian_v._Delfino)), and slander if made in a transient form.